# Can someone explain what this Email regex means

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

```
^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))
    @((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)
  +[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$
```

I could only understand parts of the regex but not the entire expression , like

`([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)`

match one or more characters that's are not the characters

```
<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"  \\  Not sure what this [\]\\  and \s@\ means
```

I could understand some of the other parts as well but not as a single entity.

Comment: Where did you got that from? Is it a string passed to `new RegExp`, or did you omit literal delimiters?

Comment: I was working with javascript validations , and came across it where it it was being used to test `email Address` I tried to understand it but in vain

Comment: http://www.myezapp.com/apps/dev/regexp/show.ws Plug it in here for a visual explination of the capture groups ect.   Here is yours:  http://tinyurl.com/ccuqrwk

Comment: The entries with a backslash in front of them are escaped characters that would have other meanings. `\]` is just the `]` character, as that would normally end the class, and `\\ ` is an escaped backslash, so just means the backslash itself.  `\s` is a special character class of whitespace.

Comment: http://regexr.com?2vkqn

Comment: [[0-9]{1,3}\. repeated is for checking an IP address

Comment: `(.....|....)` means an OR, one side or the other matches, whatever is in those sides.

Comment: If you use a regex like this in your code, and I have to come along after you and figure it out, I WILL figure out where you live! “Always code as if the guy who ends up maintaining your code is a violent psychopath who knows where you live.”

Comment: Cool..  But what does the `+` mean at the end of the Brace `\"]+`

Comment: So finally the reg is decoded then... The first part before '@' tests for the conditions of the Username with the conditions.. The part following that tests for an `IP address` or a `Domain name`.. The last part check for the extension

Comment: But what does the last part mean .. `[a-zA-Z]{2,}` I know it tests for Top level domain ...  Which is supposed to be characters `a-zA-Z` . But am confused at the part after that `{2,}` .. Min length of 2 and , .. So does it mean the maxlength can be any number

Comment: Suggested reading: http://www.amazon.co.uk/Introducing-Regular-Expressions-Michael-Fitzgerald/dp/1449392687/  (I would suggest the bible, Mastering Regular Expressions, but it appears to be out of print at the moment for some reason.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here you go:

```
^(
    (
        [^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+ // Disallow these characters any amount of times
        (
            \. // Allow dots
            [^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+ // Disallow these characters any amount of times
        )* // This group must occur once or more
    )
    | // or
    (\".+\") // Anything surrounded by quotes (Is this even legal?)
)
@ // At symbol is litterally that
(
    // IP address
    (
        \[ // Allows square bracket
        [0-9]{1,3} // 1 to three digits (for an IP address
        \. // Allows dot
        [0-9]{1,3} // 1 to three digits (for an IP address
        \. // Allows dot
        [0-9]{1,3} // 1 to three digits (for an IP address
        \. // Allows dot
        [0-9]{1,3} // 1 to three digits (for an IP address
        \] // Square bracket
    ) 
    | // OR a domain name
    (
        ([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.) // Valid domain characters are a-zA-Z0-9 plus dashes
        +
        [a-zA-Z]{2,} // The top level (anything after the dot) must be at least 2 chars long and only a-zA-Z
    )
)$
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is an easy to see illustration from debuggex.com

[image: First group]

[image: Second Group]

Comment: Awesome website! According to that, my email address with the apostrophe in my last name (over which I have no control) will not pass this regex.

Comment: Your image is actually off because when you copied and pasted the regex you got a bunch of whitespace that the OP added so we don't have to sidescroll. Cool website though, bookmarked. Here is updated: http://tinyurl.com/cklksdd

Answer (score 4):

"Not sure what this `[\]\\`  and `\s@\"` means"

`\]` is an escaped `]`
`\\` is an escaped `\`
`\s` is any white space
`@` is `@`
`\"` is an escaped `"`

"what does the + mean"

`+` means "one or more" of what precedes the `+`